# How do I keep the hyperlinking of my search results?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I've got a long list of names and categories in Excel and each item in the list hyperlinks to another worksheet in the book. Because it's unwieldy to Ctrl+F elements in the list since it's so massive, I've set up a search box using the =search, =rank, and =vlookup functions. The search box does work but the search only draws in and displays the text and these search results do not retain their original hyperlinking and that defeats the point of my database.

Long story short: How can I keep the hyperlinking of search results yielded by a search function constructed in Excel 2007?

Thanks, would be grateful for responses. Let me know if I can clarify what I am doing. 
P.S. I have more than primitively limited knowledge of VBA but if VBA is the only way to go, I'd be happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

if you can find the item they are searching for, then you can link them to the cell that has the link (inception style)

e.g. in a new workbook:

[image: a,b and c in column A]

Then, you can link to the cell that has the letter `a` with:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1]Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(MATCH("a",A1:A3,0),1),"Go To Search term")
```

This will search for `a` in the A1:A3 area of the spreadsheet, make an address using the match position, and column **1**, add the initial part of the reference, and create a hyperlink with the text "Go To Search Term" as the linking text

The hyperlink created using this formula must have the workbook and the sheet name (so you can't link to `A1`, it has to be `[MyWorkbook.xlsx]MySheet!A1`